# HTML radiobuttons in the form of matrix and it has to check only one radio button at a time in row and coloumn

Tags: asp.net, html

In HTML, radio buttons are placed like a 3*3 matrix as mentioned below. The radio buttons group give a choice that in one row and column I have to select only one radio button and if I select another then first selected button should be disable. For example in the second Row(4,5,6) And Second column(2,5,8) if I select 5th radio button then (4,6) and (2,8) should be unchecked.If I Select 1 then (2,3) and (4,7) should be unchecked. It Means that in ONE ROW and ONE COLUMN there should be only one selection.....

1,2,3

4,5,6

7,8,9

Please give me your valuable answers,thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer but a question: what if a user has made his 3 choices and he sees he wants them different. How can he do that? All options are then disabled..

Comment: my answer means chris coyier solution dont have this prob it dont disable the other buttons but chick only 1 in a row

Answer (score 0):

### Radio Buttons with 2-Way Exclusivity

this snippet is from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com) by Chris Coyier

this is in HTML CSS and JS 
convert it to asp controls

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Twix</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Snickers</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Butterfingers</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
th:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

JS

```
var col, el;

$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
   el = $(this);
   col = el.data("col");
   $("input[data-col=" + col + "]").prop("checked", false);
   el.prop("checked", true);
});
```

[DEMO](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RadioGrid/)

[Download](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RadioGrid.zip)
Thanks to Chris Coyier

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in HTML. Radio buttons act in a simple way: in any group of radio buttons, joined by the same `name` attribute value, only one can be checked at any moment, and checking an unchecked one unchecks the one that was checked. That’s it.

It’s not clear what the ultimate purpose is and what the best approach to it is. But if you have analyzed that you need a matrix like the one you describe, then you need to build the entire functionality yourself: using some elements that can be toggled, using CSS and JavaScript, behaving the way you describe.

It is best to *avoid* making the elements look like radio buttons, since that would be misleading: radio buttons as implemented in browsers work in a certain way, and making them behave in a different way would be at least confusing.